# Set a Watch for an interesting question

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I see an interesting question which has no answer yet. Later on it disappears in the timeline and I have to search for it to see if someone wrote a comment or an answer to it.

Is there a possibility to set a 'watch' on a question (sort of bookmark) to be reminded to come back later or even be notified of changes concerning this question.

If there is not, may I request this for a future feature?

Comment: Mark the question as a favorite, and then later you can click on your userprofile (in the status bar of AskUbuntu) and look at a list of your favorite questions.

Comment: Update: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/260388)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you click on that symbol seen in the screen-shot marked by that arrow this will mark a question as favorite, which you can then see in your profile under favorites, and it even shows you by a blue number on the favorites tab that there was activity, so you only need to click on this tab when there has have happened to be activity on that question.

[image]

Comment: A much better answer than my comment!

Comment: Sorry to be a bit thick - but I don't see an option in my profile page to view favourites. Where is it?